# Consul key value pair use for configuration in Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, microservices, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I tried to change my registration server from "Eureka" to "Consul" and also Consul as my config server. Service discovery with Consul is a success.But I can't understand how to get key/value pair option to bootstrap my application. Is there any possible way I can do that?

I use spring boot with below dependancies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and this is my spring boot app ConsuleDemoApplication.class

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ConsuleDemoApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsuleDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my bootstrap.yml is

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckInterval: 15s
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

  application:
    name: consul_demo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

spring boot configuration are ok. then go to consul ui using localhost:8500 and select key/value and add key value like below

[image]

then create it.then create configuration are like below

[image]

then restart your springboot application. your port change to 8084.

> note: you can use YMAL or GIT2consul for more configuration